# Transferring pdf files over the network using fread() and UDP socket

Tags: c++, c, unix

I am making a program which transfers a file over a network using UDP sockets.I have already implemented protocols dealing with missing/duplicated packets and my program runs fine with text files. But for pdf files, the program is not transferring the file correctly. I am using fread() to read the file and i am using linux. Actually i want to know whether pdf files can be stored in char arrays and then transferred over the socket and then written again on the client side into pdf. Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes", by the way. If you provide the code and tell us what's going wrong, we might be able to actually help.

Comment: sounds like you are opening pdf file in "TEXT" mode which automatically adds LF after CR on windows. While this is fine for text files, pdf (and any other binary file) get corruped

Comment: @aleguna question is tagged as `unix` so I guess it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can... If your file-transfer-stuff can transfer characters regardless of their contents. As you state, you can transfer text-files. Then you could just try to first encode your pdf into a helper format with e.g. uuencode my.pdf somename>my.uue

Comment: At the first instance: Do you handle the zero-character well (Keep it warm, if it's hungry, feed it, and be nice to it) ?